# Python requests throwing connection error when connecting to remote API through Jenkins

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, python-requests

I'm running a python script which calls an API on a remote host. While this runs fine locally, it fails when I run this script from Jenkins as a job. It fails to connect to the remote host.

I intend to automate this process hence want to run it on Jenkins.I've tried importing certs to keytool in Jenkins thinking it was some kind of cert issue but looks like the ping itself fails to the remote host.

```
url = https://remotehost:remoteport/api
payload = {
           some prams to filter request
          }

response = requests.get(url, params=payload,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASS ))
```

The build fails with following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='remotehost', port=remoteport): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /api/params 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x7fc010cb8dd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I'm not sure if this is something to change in Jenkins since it works fine locally?If yes, any pointer as to where should I be making that setting?

Comment: This sounds like a firewall/connectivity issue unrelated to Jenkins.  Does the Python script execute on the Jenkins server, without Jenkins?

Comment: I don't have access to that server directly. I can just access jenkins that is hosted on that server. However the folks managing it were not able to reach the host from that server

Comment: So is that server up?